# How can add staic block to sidebar in magento

Tags: php, magento

How can add `static block` to `side bar`

```
<block type="static block" name="static.poll" before="cart_sidebar">
```

Am using the above code but still error

Comment: Refer this link http://dx3webs.com/front/2010/11/how-to-add-a-static-block-to-the-side-bar/ Hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check it

http://dx3webs.com/front/2010/11/how-to-add-a-static-block-to-the-side-bar/

hope this will helps you

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is create "local.xml" file in your themes layout section and place below code.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="cms/block" name="your-block-identifier" before="-">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>your-block-identifier</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code ..

```
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>STATIC_BLOCK_ID</block_id></action> </block> <reference>
```

Hope this helps..